# Why isn't the event listener firing off in Lumen?

Tags: php, events, lumen

So I have event and listener classes defined as well as having them registered in the $listen array in EventServiceProvider.php. Here is the code:

```
use App\Events\EpisodeCreated;
use App\Listeners\NewEpisodeListener;

use Event;
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    protected $listen = [
        EpisodeCreated::class => [
            NewEpisodeListener::class
        ]
    ];
}
```

and then in EventServiceProvider's boot method I have the following:

```
public function boot() {
    Episode::created(function($episode) {
        Event::fire(new EpisodeCreated($episode));
    });
}
```

here is the EpisodeCreated event class:

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Episode;

class EpisodeCreated extends Event {
    public $episode;

    public function __construct(Episode $episode) {
        $this->episode = $episode;
    }
}
```

and finally the listener:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\EpisodeCreated;
use App\Facades\EventHandler;
use App\Http\Resources\ShowResource;

class NewEpisodeListener {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function handle(EpisodeCreated $event) {
        EventHandler::sendNewEpisode((new ShowResource($event->episode->show))->toArray());
    }
```

}

Lastly, I wrote the following unit test to make sure that the event is firing. It doesn't seem to be:

```
public function testNewEpisodeEventFiredOff() {
    Event::fake();

    $show = factory(Show::class)->create();
    $episode = factory(Episode::class)->create(['show_id' => $show->id]);

    Event::assertDispatched(EpisodeCreated::class);
}
```

I get an error saying that the event never got dispatched when I run phpunit. Also I added echo debug statements and while the EpisodeCreated object is being created, the NewEpisodeListener is not being fired off. Any help you guys can give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my problem seems to be that I defined the boot method in `EventServiceProvider` without calling `parent::boot()`. Since I refactored my code to not use the boot method at all, I removed it and it seems to be working better now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue and could solve this. You should add below code to your EventServiceProvider class:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->boot();
}
```

It seems `boot method` is not called when it is run by UnitTest or Command-line command I don't know why.